# making an select with case

Tags: sql

I have this table

| Id | Date | Location | Serial | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-09 | Berlin | 204408 | Rejected |
| 2 | 2022-10-09 | Roma | 233970 | Approved |
| 3 | 2022-10-09 | Paris | 233971 | Approved |
| 4 | 2022-10-09 | Paris | 233971 | Rejected |
| 5 | 2022-10-09 | Berna | 233974 | Approved |

How to write a select when i have 2 records with Same Location Same date and same Serial but different Status to show me only the Approved Status.

Also i have to show the other results as well like this:

| Id | Date | Location | Serial | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-09 | Berlin | 204408 | Rejected |
| 2 | 2022-10-09 | Roma | 233970 | Approved |
| 3 | 2022-10-09 | Paris | 233971 | Approved |
| 5 | 2022-10-09 | Berna | 233974 | Approved |

Comment: Hey SO member, welcome to the community
Would be good to share some code that you have tried out as it would help you learn and the community experts can share you their insight.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Please see [Why should I tag my RDBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`row_number()`](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/) function with a [`partition by`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) clause to assign a sequential rank number for each partition, then select accordingly.

Using `PostgreSQL`

```
WITH t
     AS (SELECT id,
                date,
                location,
                serial,
                status,
                Row_number()
                  OVER (
                    partition BY date, location, serial
                    ORDER BY status ASC) AS rn
         FROM   #have)
SELECT id,
       date,
       location,
       serial,
       status
FROM   t
WHERE  rn = 1
```

```
+----+------------+----------+--------+----------+
| id |    date    | location | serial |  status  |
+----+------------+----------+--------+----------+
|  1 | 2022-10-09 | Berlin   | 204408 | Rejected |
|  5 | 2022-10-09 | Berna    | 233974 | Approved |
|  3 | 2022-10-09 | Paris    | 233971 | Approved |
|  2 | 2022-10-09 | Roma     | 233970 | Approved |
+----+------------+----------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: Note: This relies on alphabetical order of statuses.

Answer (score 1):

You can write this query (available in all DBMS known to me):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable AS T1
WHERE T1.Status = 'Approved'
  OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM YourTable AS T2 WHERE T1.Date=T2.Date AND T1.Location=T2.Location AND T1.Serial=T2.Serial AND T2.Status='Approved')
```

Take all *Approved* and all others where *Approved* does not exist.